# Meaning of sentences using "has/have/had been" and "is" with nouns

Tags: difference, tense, sentence-meaning

I read some sentences where writers used nouns with *has/have/had been*.

What exactly does it mean?

Examples:

> She has been an able administrator.
>   Her mother had been an American.
>   He has been mad at me.

What if I say?

> She is an able Administrator.
>   Her mother was an American.
>   He is mad at me.

Please explain the difference.

Also when and how to use *has/have/had been* and *is*?

Comment: **has/have/had + Past Participle** combinations are used to form the Perfect tenses: Present Perfect, Past Perfect, Future Perfect. You might google for "present perfect", "past perfect" if you wish to learn more.

Comment: This is a very complicated topic. You may also wish to consult our long post on [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32).

Comment: Whole websites are devoted to answering this. [English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses.htm) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the conjugation table of **to be** in a basic grammar:

Tenses I: I am, I was, I will be, I would be

Tenses II: I have been, I had been, I will have been, I would have been

After will/would follows bare infinitive or infinitive perfect.

After have/has/had follows stem form 3: been (past participle).

Comment: I have already gone through all but unable to understand. Please explain

Comment: Rogermue, dont write it as answer.

Comment: ELL is not a place to ask for grammar lessons. You need to consult a site such as English Club.

Comment: Or simply get a grammar.